# Mocking a HTTP server in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, http, rest, mocking

I'm writing a REST client and I need to mock a HTTP server in my tests. What would be the most appropriate library to do that? It would be great if I could create expected HTTP requests and compare them to actual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [HTTPretty](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty), a HTTP client mock library for Python helps you focus on the client side.

Comment: note httpretty is not a web server but patch python socket module

Answer (score 9):

You can also create a small mock server on your own.
I am using a small web server called [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def callback():
    return flask.jsonify(list())

app.add_url_rule("users", view_func=callback)
app.run()
```

This will spawn a server under http://localhost:5000/users executing the callback function.

I created a gist to provide a working example with shutdown mechanism etc.
https://gist.github.com/eruvanos/f6f62edb368a20aaa880e12976620db8

Answer (score 7):

You can do this without using any external library by just running a temporary HTTP server.

For example mocking a https://api.ipify.org?format=json

```
"""Unit tests for ipify"""

import http.server
import threading
import unittest
import urllib.request


class MockIpifyHTTPRequestHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    """HTTPServer mock request handler"""

    def do_GET(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        """Handle GET requests"""
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'{"ip":"1.2.3.45"}')

    def log_request(self, code=None, size=None):
        """Don't log anything"""


class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    """Unit tests for urlopen"""

    def test_urlopen(self):
        """Test urlopen ipify"""
        server = http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer(
            ("127.0.0.127", 9999), MockIpifyHTTPRequestHandler
        )
        with server:
            server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
            server_thread.daemon = True
            server_thread.start()

            request = request = urllib.request.Request("http://127.0.0.127:9999/")
            with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
                result = response.read()
            server.shutdown()

        self.assertEqual(result, b'{"ip":"1.2.3.45"}')
```

Alternative solution I found is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34929900/15862

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on [pytest-httpserver](https://pytest-httpserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest).

It launches a server on the spot - localhost, that is closed on teardown.

```
# the httpserver is a fixture automatically provided by the library
async def test_get_location(httpserver: HTTPServer):
   # setup the expected calls to the server
   httpserver.expect_oneshot_request(
      method="GET",
      uri="/locations/location_123",
   )

   # now you can call httpserver.url_for("/locations/location_123") with any HTTP client
   # IRL you'd inject the base URL (httpserver.url_for("") in your component under test;
   # then you'd call the method under test which would consume the setup calls
```

super fast, clean, realistic, and no mocks involved.

Answer (score 0):

[Mockintosh](https://github.com/up9inc/mockintosh) seems like another option.