# Python 3 urlopen context manager mocking

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, testing

I am new to testing and need some help here.

Assuming having this method:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def get_posts():
    with urlopen('some url here') as data:
        return json.loads(data.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

The question is how to test this method (using mock.patch decorator if possible)?

What I have now:

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.urlopen')
def test_get_post(self, mocked_urlopen):
    mocked_urlopen.__enter__ = Mock(return_value=self.test_data)
    mocked_urlopen.__exit__ = Mock(return_value=False)
    ...
```

But it does not seem to be working.

P.S. Is there any convenient way to work with data variable (which type is HTTPResponse) in test so it could just be simple string?

Comment: I am not familiar with the `mock` library, but maybe you can check [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) documents for more details.

Comment: `self.test_data` must be an object that has `read()` method, not string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I have written simple class to simulate context manager.

```
class PatchContextManager:

    def __init__(self, method, enter_return, exit_return=False):
        self._patched = patch(method)
        self._enter_return = enter_return
        self._exit_return = exit_return

    def __enter__(self):
        res = self._patched.__enter__()
        res.context = MagicMock()
        res.context.__enter__.return_value = self._enter_return
        res.context.__exit__.return_value = self._exit_return
        res.return_value = res.context
        return res

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        return self._patched.__exit__()
```

Usage:

```
with PatchContextManager('mymodule.method', 'return_string') as mocked:
    a = mymodule.method(47) # a == 'return_string'
    mocked.assert_called_with(47)
    ...
```

Answer (score 30):

I was fighting with this as well, and finally figured it out. (Python 3 syntax):

```
import urllib.request
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class TestUrlopen(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('urllib.request.urlopen')
    def test_cm(self, mock_urlopen):
        cm = MagicMock()
        cm.getcode.return_value = 200
        cm.read.return_value = 'contents'
        cm.__enter__.return_value = cm
        mock_urlopen.return_value = cm

        with urllib.request.urlopen('http://foo') as response:
            self.assertEqual(response.getcode(), 200)
            self.assertEqual(response.read(), 'contents')

    @patch('urllib.request.urlopen')
    def test_no_cm(self, mock_urlopen):
        cm = MagicMock()
        cm.getcode.return_value = 200
        cm.read.return_value = 'contents'
        mock_urlopen.return_value = cm

        response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://foo')
        self.assertEqual(response.getcode(), 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.read(), 'contents')
        response.close()
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the difference between no_cm and cm?

Comment: @EralpB cm means he shows an example using urlopen as a context manager, the no_cm shows an example without using it as context manager.

Answer (score 1):

`with urlopen('some url here') as data` is a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers)

Also, a file can be used as a context manager, so a better approach here is to use `io.StringIO`

```
import io
import json
import urllib.request
from unittest.mock import patch


def get_posts():
    with urllib.request.urlopen('some url here') as data:
        return json.load(data)


def test_get_posts():
    data = io.StringIO('{"id": 123}')
    with patch.object(urllib.request, 'urlopen', return_value=data):
        assert get_posts() == {"id": 123}
```

Comment: That did the trick for me as well. To mock the result of `urlopen` more accurately, consider using an `io.BytesIO` object instead (if needed, convert your string with `"yourstring".encode('utf-8')`).

Answer (score 0):

here is my take on this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from unittest.mock import patch

class Mock():
    def __init__(self, request, context):
        return None

    def read(self):
        return self

    def decode(self, arg):
        return ''

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        raise StopIteration


 with patch('urllib.request.urlopen',  Mock):
    # do whatever over here
```